# How to use a class created by the entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I have a project coming up so I decided to look at the entity framework.  If I don't have to create a data manager I think this would be the way to go, if it works.  I see lots of things about it but none of them are clear.

It created this class

```
namespace EFTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class SalesRepresentative
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How do I use it?  Looking for examples I see things like this:

```
using (var ctx = new Context())
{
    Employee emp = new Employee() { name = "Prashant" };
    ctx.Employees.Add(emp);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have a file called Model.Comntext with no context class in it.  I tried changing it to dBContext but that doesn't work either.

I also found this:

```
CustomersComponent custc = new CustomersComponent();
Customers cust = custc.getCustomer(Id);
txtName.Text = cust.Name;
ddlCategories.SelectedValue = cust.Category.Id.ToString();
```

Well that has a Customer and a CustomerComponent.  I have no such Component classes.  I've spent half a day looking into this and am starting to wonder if the Entity Framework is a cousin of Microsoft Bob.  Unless someone can tell me what I'm missing I will have to write my own data manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resume step by step:

1 - Create a console project.

2 - Install EF using Nuget: *Install-Package EntityFramework*

3 - Create SalesRepresentative:

```
namespace EF {
    public partial class SalesRepresentative {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

4 - Create GeneralContext

```
namespace EF {
    public class GeneralContext: DbContext {

        public DbSet<SalesRepresentative> SalesRepresentatives { get; set; }
    }
}
```

5 - So:

```
namespace EF {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            using (var ctx = new GeneralContext()) {
                SalesRepresentative emp = new SalesRepresentative() { Name = "Prashant" };
                ctx.SalesRepresentatives.Add(emp);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In the App.config file (or web.config) you should customize the connection string.

Comment: Thanks Seba, +1.  The tutorial I was using never mentioned the GeneralContext class.  There's so much out there it is hard to tell the complete from the incomplete when you are trying to learn something.  You got me moving forward, thanks again!